# How to constrain a parameter in a mixed effect model in R?

Tags: lme4, r-lavaan

I'm trying to fit a mixed effect model with a constrained parameter, and am struggling to make it work. Adding a small bit of complexity, is that one of the terms should be a polynomial.

Essentially what I'm looking for is something like the following, where var 1 is fixed at a certain value.

**mod1 <- lmer(outcome ~ var1 + poly(var2,2) + (1 | Study), df)**

It seems like it can be done using lmer with the Nelder-Mead option, but I can quite wrap my head around how to make it work.

I've also tried using the lavaan package, but I've never used it before and am getting hung up somewhere. Here is an example...

```
library(lavaan)

reprex_df <- structure(list(outcome = c(0.54, 5.06, 15.35, 5.4, 5.3, 1.57, 
                                        2.11, 2.71, 9.09, 7.96, 28.8, 4.4, 3.38, 15.43, 4.05), var1 = c(0.55, 
                                                                                                        3.42, 2.24, 2.24, 3.44, 1.82, 1.82, 2.23, 5.41, 2.61, 6.94, 3.98, 
                                                                                                        2.23, 5.29, 3.28), var2 = c(111, 235, 60, 197, 369, 342.78, 240.99, 
                                                                                                                                    406.5, 264, 263.8, 76, 679, 338, 116, 683), study = c("Study 1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "Study 2",  "Study 2",  "Study 2", "Study 3", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "Study 4", "Study 4", "Study 6", "Study 5", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "Study 7", "Study 2", "Study 7", "Study 6", 
                                                                                                                                                                                   "Study 5", "Study 2")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I think I can make a basic model (without the polynomial)

```
reprex_df

test.model <- '  outcome  ~ var1 + var2 + study'

test.model <- sem(test.model, 
                    data = reprex_df, cluster = "study")
coef(test.model)
```

But when I try and constrain var1 to a specific value I'm getting an error

```
test.model.constr <- '  outcome    ~ var1 + var2 + study

var1 == 4.87
'

test.model.constr <- sem(test.model.constr, 
                  data = reprex_df, cluster = "study")
```

Any help in constraining the parameter (using either lmer or lavaan) and/or adding a polynomial term in lavaan would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tricky because `lmer` "profiles out" the fixed-effect parameters, i.e. they're not explicitly fitted as part of the nonlinear optimization step.

Assuming `var1` is numeric/continuous and we want to set a coefficient of `b`, how about

```r
mod1 <- lmer(outcome ~ 1 + offset(b*var1) + poly(var2,2) + (1 | Study), df)
```

? This adds the term `b*var1` directly to the model.

The `glmmTMB` package has a `map` argument that allows the user to fix any of the parameters explicitly to a particular value (or to constrain several parameters to have a common value).

Comment: p.s. Ben I tried copying/adapting your posted glmer example but got stuck and couldn't make it work! https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/108675_02daa6544e584a928b296c3bca9a65d5.html